# Tailwind Responsive Design

Tags: responsive-design, tailwind-css

I'm new to Tailwind and I'm reading responsive design chapter , I know by default, Tailwind uses a mobile-first breakpoint system and define some classnames such as sm , md , xl ... for min- modifiers , max-sm , max-xl ... for max-modifiers

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')
module.exports = {
   theme: {
      screens: {
        ...defaultTheme.screens
      }
   }
}
```

If I delete the code "...defaultTime.screens" , min- and max- modifiers are no longer available as expected , and if I add a new key in the next line :

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')
module.exports = {
   theme: {
      screens: {
        ...defaultTheme.screens,
        'myResponsive': '300px'
      }
   }
}
```

It will add **myResponsive** class name as a min- modifier and **max-myResponsive** class name as a max- modifier , which is still expected , but if I alter the above code to :

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')
module.exports = {
   theme: {
      screens: {
        ...defaultTheme.screens,
        'myResponsive': {'min': '300px'}
      }
   }
}
```

Event that it will add **myResponsive** class name as a min- modifier , but **max-myResponsive** class name will no longer be added as a max- modifier , and now I couldn't even use `max-sm` , `max-xl` ... classname for max- modifier

Could anyone tell me why ? I think it is about when we want to use a custom max- modifier , we should define it with an "object" type value and if we want to prevent from overriding the default max- responsive modifiers , we should define the setting in `theme.extend.screens` key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the restrictions detailed in this pull request that added the `min-*` and `max-*` variants](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/9558#user-content-restrictions):

> To ensure proper sorting we've made the decision to restrict the use of these features to screens that are "simple", meaning that they are `min-width`-based, and consist of only string values that use the same units.
>
> […]
>
> While these are invalid and will disable these new features:
>
> ```js
> module.exports = {
>   theme: {
>     screens: {
>       sm: "640px",
>       md: "768px",
>       lg: "1024px",
>       xl: "1280px",
>       "2xl": "1536px",
>       portrait: { raw: "(orientation: portrait)" },
>     },
>   },
> };
> ```
>
> ```js
> module.exports = {
>   theme: {
>     extends: {
>       screens: {
>         xs: { min: "320px" },
>       },
>     },
>   },
> };
> ```

Thus, to be able to use `min-*` or `max-*` variants for *any* `screens` values, consider changing your custom `screen.myResponsive` value to a simple string value:

```js
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')
module.exports = {
   theme: {
      screens: {
        ...defaultTheme.screens,
        'myResponsive': '300px',
      }
   }
}
```